# concat column name depending on value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I need to concat column name depending on row value. Below is my table format:-

**Table Name = tbl_occupancy**

[image]

so from this table, I need to concat below column if their value is **1**:-

1. working_people
2. owner_occupied
3. students
4. dss_referrals
5. local_authority

output would be in below format:-

```
Working People/Owner Occupied/Students/Dss Referrals/Local Authority 
when all of these columns value are one.
```

**Suppose if working_people & dss_referrals = 1 then my output will be below:-**

```
Working People/Dss Referrals
```

trying for one day. not found any solution till now.

**I need this output in a single row mentioned above. Because this query will work as an sub query in my report module. And this output will be shown as a column in xls sheet.**

Any help plz.

Comment: If one/more of their values is not `'1'`, how do you want the output? Can you also post a tabulated expected output with other columns and their names included?

Comment: @Ravinder check my edit and if possible remove negative vote. I need answer of this question.

Comment: I am not the person who downvoted you.

Comment: It seems, [*Answer by @MKhalidJunaid*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22061706/767881) is as expected from you. What change you still are expecting from it?

Comment: @Ravinder I'm finding the proper solution till now. If I found it, I'll post it here.

Comment: Well, does it mean that the solution is not matching as what you expected as defined in your posting? If yes, you should explain more on why it is not so.

Comment: Because, unless you post why it is not up to the expectations, I feel, the Owner of the Answer, people other than you, may still trying to think on *what was wrong!?*, which, again I feel, is not correct.

Comment: @Ravinder I have edited. check the highlighted part. Is it ok now?

Comment: I assume, you know that to retrieve a single row we need to pass where condition. In your case, it would need an `id` only or both of (`risk_reference`, `risk_version`)

Comment: @Ravinder yes You are correct. (risk_reference, risk_version) checking needed.

Comment: @Ravinder I posted my answer. If You wish You may check it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` inside the `CONCAT()` function

```
SELECT
DISTINCT risk_reference, 
CONCAT(
CASE WHEN `working_people` = 1 THEN 'Working People /' ELSE '' END ,
CASE WHEN `owner_occupied` = 1 THEN 'Owner Occupied /' ELSE '' END ,
CASE WHEN `students` = 1 THEN 'Students /' ELSE '' END ,
CASE WHEN `dss_referrals` = 1 THEN 'Dss Referrals/' ELSE '' END ,
CASE WHEN `local_authority` = 1 THEN 'Local Authority' ELSE '' END 
) `concat_columns`
FROM 
`table`
```

**EDIT:**
You can use `DISTINCT` to get the distinct results but in your table you have multiple rows  so there will be multiple results although you can use a `GROUP BY risk_reference` but its not good to use without aggregate functions

Comment: Or you can use `CONCAT_WS` so there will be no trailing slash ;) Then you'll need to return `NULL` if the field is 0

Comment: @core1024 yes `CONCAT_WS` can be a substitute but avisheks has provided using `CONCAT_WS`

Comment: Your sql is giving me multiple row output. I need single row.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanks for Your answer. It's giving output. I'm giving upvote for this. But I need some smart solution. So I'm not able to accept Your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am using below query for my solution:-

```
select group_concat("/",col.column_name) as hazards from information_schema.columns 
  as col inner join db_name.`tbl_occupancy` as oc  on col.table_schema="db_name" 
  and col.table_name = "tbl_occupancy" and col.column_name in (
           if(oc.working_people=1,"working_people",""),
           if(oc.owner_occupied=1,"owner_occupied",""),
           if(oc.students=1,"students",""),
           if(oc.dss_referrals=1,"dss_referrals",""),
           if(oc.local_authority=1,"local_authority","")
    );
```

Comment: Instead of `group_concat("/",col.column_name)` use `group_concat(col.column_name separator '/')`. You will get answer as expected in your posting.

Comment: @Ravinder ok. Will do. Thanks for Your suggestion. 1 question. Does my answer good quality or bad quality?

Comment: Why don't you just run `explain` on your answer and [*Answer by @MKhalidJunaid*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22061706/767881). That tells a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("/",
IF(working_people=1,"working_people",""),
IF(owner_occupied=1,"owner_occupied"),
IF(students=1,"students",""),
IF(dss_referrals=1,"dss_referrals",""),
IF(local_authority=1,"local_authority","")) AS result
FROM tbl_occupancy;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

> "concat-ws"

. It does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any NULL values after the separator and argument.

```
      `mysql> SELECT CONCAT_WS(',','Test',NULL,'1');
              output -> 'Test,1'`
```

Comment: plz read the question properly. I know how to and where to use concat_ws().